# Можно ли какими-либо путями использовать табличный индекс в сравнении (больше-меньше) дат?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-boot

Есть запрос `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.date <= date`, где *date* - любая дата. Вопрос простой: возможно ли тут применение индексирования для быстрого поиска удовлетворяющих условию значений? Будет ли толк от создания такого рода индекса `CREATE INDEX idx_table$date ON table (date)`? Или здесь нужно как-то иначе его создавать?

Насколько я знаю, индексы работаю с операциями равенства, чтобы по значению моментально найти полную запись типа `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.date = date`

P.S. Данный запрос выполняется с помощью Spring Data JPA, поэтому может быть кто-то знает как оптимизировать запрос через язык программирования, а не на уровне базы данных.

Comment: *Будет ли толк от создания такого рода индекса CREATE INDEX idx_table$date ON table (date)?* Если процент отбираемых значений невелик (5-7%, не более), то от индекса будет толк. иначе прямой скан таблицы выгоднее, а если всё же заставить сервер использовать индекс, то получится медленнее.

Comment: А если можно, немного поподробнее как связан процент отбираемых значений с работой индекса?

Comment: Если используется сканирование таблицы, читается только тело таблицы, причём последовательно. Если используется индекс, читается сначала индекс, а потом нужные блоки тела таблицы, причём практически рандомно. Экспериментально найден этот самый порог селективности, на котором в среднем индекс становится выгоднее прямого скана. Конечно, там есть хренова гора влияющих факторов - но в среднем по больнице оно именно так.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое! А ещё хотел узнать у Вас, если можно: каким образом в запросе будет участвовать индекс, если он, насколько мне известно, работает исключительно с операциями равенства? Или я имею какие-то неверные представления?

Comment: Угу, неверные...

Comment: Индекс - это как алфавитный указатель в какой нибудь книге, все что вы можете сделать глазами по указателю в книге, то может сделать и индекс. если вы например хотите взять все статьи от А до Г, то вам будет несложно просмотреть часть указателя в этом диапазоне.

Comment: @Mike а что если индекс составной? К примеру запрос `SELECT * FROM table WHERE table .status='some-status' AND table.code='some-code' AND table.date <= custom_date`, Будет ли в такой случае смысл от индекса `CREATE INDEX idx_table$stcodestdate ON table (status, code, date)`? Если одиночный индекс в голове уложился, то с составным есть пробелы. Просто я сейчас тестирую это на 83 млн. записей и не вижу никаких приростов. Запрос выполняется 300 ms что с индексом, что без него.

Comment: Стоит добавить что на поля `status` и `code` созданы индексы

Comment: *Будет ли в такой случае смысл от индекса* Да. Сперва будет найден кусок, соответствующий значению первого поля, в нём кусочек, соответствующий значению второго поля, а внутри этого кусочка будет поиск по значению третьего поля. *на поля status и code созданы индексы* При наличии композитного индекса существование индекса по первому поля практически на 100% бессмысленно.

Comment: @Akina то есть если я добавлю композитный индекс на эти три поля, то индексы на поля status и code лучше удалить? Просто есть примеры запросов, когда исключительно по этим двум полям изолировано идёт запрос

Comment: *то есть если я добавлю композитный индекс на эти три поля, то индексы на поля status и code лучше удалить?* Вы говорите не думая. Это плохо. В индексе по status записи упорядочены по status. В индексе по code записи упорядочены по code. В композите записи упорядочены по status, а значения code идут вперемешку (а по порядку - только в пределах одного значения status). Посему при наличии композитного индекса только индекс по его префиксу лишний и может быть удалён, а вот второй - скорее всего должен остаться.

Comment: Да тут мало думать, тут знать нужно) Спасибо!

Comment: Вернемся к алфавитному указателю. Предположим, вы решили сделать композитный индекс. Отлично, представьте, что вы на бумаге к книге решили вместо указателя по алфавиту сделать указатель где данные будут отсортированы по полям status, code, date. Т.е. идет status=1 внутри него список всех code (сортированный) и для каждого code список всех date. И опять же представляете как  и что по нему можно найти. Хотите получить все с status=1 Элементарно, список собственно уже готов (поэтому индекс отдельно по status уже точно не нужен). ...

Comment: status и code одновременно - то же нет проблем, данные в списке так и лежат. А вот например просто по code - проблема, вам надо будет перебрать в таком списке все возможные status, что бы в каждом поискать code.